# Ambiguous identifier in Scala: Where is this defined in the SLS?

Tags: scala

Consider the definition of the Scala classes `p.X`, `T` and `Y`:

```
package p {
  object X {
    val y: Int = 21
  }
}

class T { val X = new Y(42) }
class Y(val y: Int)
val p = new T
```

After these definitions the question arises what the identifier `p.X.y` refer to:

1. to the value `y=21` in class `p.X`, or
2. to the value `X.y=42` referenced over the value `p`?

A test reveals, that variant 2 is taken.

Question: where is this defined in the SLS?

**EDIT**

To clarify the situation I have changed/extended the above example to the following compilation unit:

```
package p {
  object X { val y: Int = 21 }
}

class T { val X = new Y(42) }
class Y(val y: Int)
object p extends T

object Test extends App { println(p.X.y) }
```

It is not clear to me how exactly the definitions of SLS section 2 have to be applied here. The scope of the application `Test` defines no bindings, and in the scope of the compilation unit the two bindings `object p` and `package p` (or object `p.x`) seem to have the same precedence.

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 2 of the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), **Identifiers, Names and Scopes**

> A binding in some inner scope shadows
>   bindings of lower precedence in the same scope as well as bindings of the same or
>   lower precedence in outer scopes

This section goes on to gives the *rules of precedence* and some examples. In your example, the last declaration of `p` (thre *reference*) shadows the former (the *object*)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. According to the [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), both the local definition of `val p` and the package clause `package p {...}` have the highest precedence. Probably the definition of the scopes is not very clear in my example.

Comment: @Dominik Yes, but `package p` is an outer scope, isn't it? `val p` is not defined on the package -- that would be illegal unless it was a package object. Outer scopes of _same_ or lower precedence are shadowed.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral I have clarified the example. For me, the two definitions `object p` and `package p` are in the same scope. Does section 2 SLS really define how qualified identifiers are resolved?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral exactly, and surprisingly this compiles just fine. I realized that the original question was not well posed as, as you said, the `val` definition has to occur within a scope which is somewhere inside the top-level (or empty-package) scope.

Comment: @Dominik This happens when something is in the "default scope", which is a weird Java thing. Note that this object cannot be used from any other file, for instance. On a normal package hierarchy, you'll get an error.